# Could it be possible that dark matter could one day be used as fuel by humans?

Tags: dark-matter

First we will have to know exactly what dark matter is. At the moment "dark matter" is a hypothetical type of matter that causes a specific gravitational effect. That is, we can measure an effect on the universe that does not agree with relativity unless we include "something" that causes the effect. This something has been called dark matter.

Comment: It is easy to generate an infinite number of questions of the form "Can X be used for Y?".  Without a proposed mechanism, every one of those  questions is off topic.

Answer (score 2):

> Could it be possible that dark matter could one day be used as fuel by humans?

Since dark matter does not interact with ordinary matter through the electromagnetic force, the strong nuclear force or the weak nuclear force, and since it is very spread out (there are no dark matter planets or asteroids that we could mine) then it is very difficult to see how we could ever use it as fuel.

Answer (score 0):

Fuel requires the fast release of huge amounts of available energy, which in turn requires strong interactions (e.g. electromagnetic in the chase of chemical fuel, Strong in the case of nuclear reactions, etc). Dark matter doesn't seem to be doing that, but of course the definite answer can only be given once the actual nature of dark matter has been discovered. In the meantime, it's perhaps more interesting to contemplate whether it could be used as an inter-galactic communication channel.

Answer (score 0):

Not likely: nuclear fusion and fission happen naturally in nature Dark matter doesn't seem to be naturally fuelling anything in space.